# Extract data from the database and save it as an Excel file using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written a web application to get the data from the database in which the user would select the start date and end date of the data they want to have and then submit which later is saved to an Excel file.

The application only works when not attached to the form, however it doesn't do anything when I include the start date and end date.

Here is my `HomeController` code snippet:

```
namespace Task1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new FormBoard();
            
            var form = new FormBoard.Form();
            form.StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            form.EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            
            return View(model);
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportExcelData(FormBoard viewModel)
        {
            IEnumerable<ReportData> results;
            var connection = @"server=remoteserver;Database=introsw;Uid=root;Pwd=12345";

            using var con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            {
                 con.Open();
                 results = con.Query<ReportData>(@"SELECT 
                         document_date as [DocumentDate],
                         document_number as [DocumentNumber], 
                         description as [Description],
                         project__code as [ProjectCode],
                         project__name as [ProjectName],
                         client__name as [ClientName],
                         client__account as [ClientAccount],
                         total_incl_vat as [TotalIncVat]
                             FROM
                         customer_documents_full_view
                             WHERE 
                         document_date BETWEEN 'StartDate' AND 'EndDate'
                          ");
                 
             XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
             workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample").Cell(1, 1).SetValue(results);
             var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                 
             MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
             workbook.SaveAs((Stream) memoryStream);
             memoryStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                 
             var content = memoryStream.ToArray();
             Console.Write(content);
                 
             return File(content, contentType, "Datafile.xlsx");
        } 
        
        public class ReportData
        {
            public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
            public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
            public string ProjectName { get; set; }
            public string ClientName { get; set; }
            public string ClientAccount { get; set; }
            public Decimal TotalIncVat { get; set; }
        }        
    }

    
}
```

My `view model` form is as follows;

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Task1.ViewModels
{
    public class FormBoard
    {
       
        public class Form
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            
            //  start date 
            [Required]
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            // end data
            [Required]
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            
        
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

and finally my `view` is as follow, which is what I want to get the data for the specified dates by the user in the database;

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model Task1.ViewModels.FormBoard

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        
        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
                
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Fill in Date</h2>
            <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" >
                <div>
                    <label >Start:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="StartDate" 
                           class="input-validation-error"
                           data-val="true"
                           data-val-required="The start date field is required"
                           id="StartDate" value="">
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <label >End:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="EndDate" >
                </div>

                <div class="center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" >Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the form displays in the browser and once the user click submit, then an Excel file should be generated with an option to save it from the data from the db with the user's specified dates.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out so what I did was change a line in my view file,

`<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" >`

changed to:

`<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ExportExcelData" >`

and have added a class in my `Controller`

```
public class ReportParams
        {
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            
        }
```

Which I then changed my `ExportExcelData` class to;

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportExcelData(ReportParams reportParams)
             {
                 IEnumerable<ReportData> results;
                 var connection = @"server=remoteserver;Database=introsw;Uid=root;Pwd=12345";
                 using var con = new SqlConnection(connection);
                
                 con.Open();
                 results = con.Query<ReportData>(@"SELECT 
                         document_date as [DocumentDate],
                         document_number as [DocumentNumber], 
                         description as [Description],
                         project__code as [ProjectCode],
                         project__name as [ProjectName],
                         client__name as [ClientName],
                         client__account as [ClientAccount],
                         total_incl_vat as [TotalIncVat]
                             FROM
                         customer_documents_full_view
                             WHERE 
                         document_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                          ", reportParams);
                 
                 XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
                 workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample").Cell(1, 1).SetValue(results);
                 var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                 
                 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                 workbook.SaveAs((Stream) memoryStream);
                 memoryStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                 
                 var content = memoryStream.ToArray();
                 Console.Write(content);
                 Console.WriteLine("Export Excel Data");

             
                 return File(content, contentType, "Datafile.xlsx");


             }
```